# Having issues with back face culling, I'm using the cross product of the two vertices and rendering if > 0

Tags: vb.net, 3d

If I render my cube without back face cull everything seems to render properly. I can scale, translate and rotate as needed. When I enable the back face cull I lose the 4 sides, keeping the front and back triangles, and the 4 sides remain missing even with rotation of any direction. And the front/back remain regardless of rotation.

```
For Each triangle In Cube.Triangles
    ' Calculate signed area of the triangle (cross product of two edges)
    Dim v1 As Point3d = triangle.Vertices(1) - triangle.Vertices(0)
    Dim v2 As Point3d = triangle.Vertices(2) - triangle.Vertices(0)
    Dim crossProduct = v1.Cross(v2)

    ' Check the sign of the z-component of the cross product
    Dim windingOrder As Integer = Math.Sign(crossProduct.Z)

    ' Apply back-face culling
    If windingOrder > 0 Then
        ' Render the triangle
```

My cross product method looks like:

```
Public Function Cross(p As Point3d) As Point3d

    Dim x1 As Single = Me.Y * p.Z - Me.Z * p.Y
    Dim y1 As Single = Me.Z * p.X - Me.X * p.Z
    Dim z1 As Single = Me.X * p.Y - Me.Y * p.X
    Return New Point3d(x1, y1, z1)

End Function
```

I'm at a loss where, what to do to resolve, this is my first try at a 3d engine.

Comment: Are the faces defined such that the points are in the correct order? That's an easy one to get wrong.

Comment: That is what I found, thanks for your response.

Comment: The Wikipedia page [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) shows the maths you need - have you considered where the triangles are relative to the viewpoint in your calculations?